# What's wrong with 很多同学坐着在草地上?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

```
很多同学坐着在草地上 => My textbook gives me the correct sentence: 很多同学坐在草地上.
```

But I think the original one is not wrong.

(1) 很多同学坐着在草地上. Many students are sitting on the grass.

(2) 很多同学坐在草地上. Many students sit on the grass.

**Is what I think correct?** Does anyone have any better explanation?

Answer (score 4):

The particle 着 indicates [the continuous aspect](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Aspect_particle_%22zhe%22), and if we want to use this particle, the appropriate structure is:

> Place + Verb + 着 + [Noun Phrase]
>   <sub>[Alternative existential sentences; Pattern with 着](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Alternative_existential_sentences#Pattern_with_.E7.9D.80), Chinese Grammar Wiki</sub>

So the "place" should come before the verb ([as usual](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Indicating_location_with_%22zai%22_before_verbs)), i.e.:

> 很多同学**在草地上**坐着。

It's continuous, so it is happening and will continue to happen.  The context will give the time period in which it occurs.  It means what you said: "Many students are sitting on the grass." (Although, I feel 同学 is better translated to "classmates" than "students", but this depends on context.)

We generally think of 坐 as intransitive, i.e., it doesn't take an object (i.e., "I sit" 我坐着)  For comparison, 吃 can be transitive (e.g., "I eat food" 我吃着饭).  Although we can say:

> 很多同学坐着地铁。 (Many classmates are taking the subway.)

but here 坐着 means "take", and 地铁 is the object of the sentence.

The official version:

> 很多同学坐在草地上。

uses a different grammar structure with the "special verb" 坐:

> Subj. + [Special Verb] + 在 + Location
>   <sub>[Special cases of "zai" following verbs](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Special_cases_of_%22zai%22_following_verbs), Chinese Grammar Wiki</sub>

And I believe your translation is correct: "Many students sit on the grass."

Comment: Thanks Becky. If I use Verb + 着 + Place to describe two ongoing actions, is it correct? For example: 他坐着在沙发上看报纸。(He is sitting on sofa and reading newspaper)

Comment: Hmm, I’m not sure (maybe that’s another question), but I’d instinctively put the 着 after the 看, since 坐在沙发上 describes the location.

Comment: @Jenny It should be 他坐在沙发上看报纸 or 他在沙发上坐着看报纸.

Comment: @dan thank you, but why cannot write "他坐着在沙发上看报纸"?

Comment: @Jenny 'Why' is unanswerable in language.  :(